# Convert String into Class for TitleWindow

Tags: flex4, popup

I don't know if this is possible, I am pulling the names for `TitleWindows` from my database as strings.

Then from my main application I have to launch the TitleWindow. So in my function I need to convert the name of the TitleWindow which is a String to a Class, because the PopUpManager accepts a Class. Below is my code.

When launching my application and trying to launch the TitleWindow I am getting the error:

```
Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type Class.
```

I don't want to hard code the name of my popUp in the PopUpManager, that is why I am doing it like this.   Any way to work around this?

```
public function getScreen(screenName:String):void
{
    var screen_Name:Class = new Class();
    screen_Name = screenName;

    var popUpWindow:TitleWindow = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, screen_Name, false) as TitleWindow;
    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(popUpWindow);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had to do something very similar recently. Here is the function I wrote to do it:

```
    //You have to provice the package signature
    private var viewPackage:String = "org.bishop";

    //In my case, event.type is the name of a class
    var className: String = viewPackage + "." + event.type;
                try{
                    var classRef:Class = getDefinitionByName(className) as Class;

                    viewNavigator.pushView(classRef);               
                }   
                catch(e:ViewError){
                    trace(e.message);
                    logger.debug(e.message);
                }
```

Note: for the class to be created correctly, you will need to include both an import statement:

```
import org.bishop.Login;
```

and also declare a variable of the class in the code as follows:

```
Login;
```

otherwise the classes will not be available to be created.